# jersey (web service) : the advantages of StreamingOutput and the best way for create downloading API

Tags: java, rest, jersey, streaming, download

I had used this method for creating an API for downloading files using jersey `JAX-RS` for my `REST` web service :

```
public Response returnFile(String filePath,String fileName,MediaType type) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    String[] filePart = filePath.split("\\.");
    String fileEnd = filePart[filePart.length - 1];
    return Response.ok(file, type)
        .header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" 
            + URLEncoder.encode(fileName + "." + fileEnd,"UTF-8") + "\"" ) 
            .build(); 
}
```

but someone told me this may have performance issues and cause `OutOfMemory` exception.

so I recently searched for creating an API like this and I found out most of the examples are using `StreamingOutput`.

so what is the advantage of using `StreamingOutput`? does it better to use it in my method instead of `File`? and if anyone says the best ways for creating these kinds of APIs (APIs for downloading files), I will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is more memory efficient. Read this article for more info: https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-streaming-response

Comment: tell your answer more specifically

Comment: ohhhhh, this question is so old and I found the answer long ago, but I am thankful that u put ur time on this